# Datarepeater delete only deleting top record

Tags: c#, datarepeater

I have a datarepeater and the following code ONLY deletes the FIRST record regardless of which one is selected.  I am not entirely convinced this is the correct way to do it with a datarepeater but I could not find a better solution.  I need to be able to select any record and delete it.

```
    //delete document
    private void cmdDeleteDoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.dataRepeater1.CurrentItemIndex == 0)
        {

            //begin reset
            this.dataRepeater1.BeginResetItemTemplate();
            // Delete Row Here

            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
            newCityCollectionDataSet.DocumentsRow SelectedRow;

            SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)documentsBindingSource.Current;
            SelectedRow = (newCityCollectionDataSet.DocumentsRow)SelectedRowView.Row;


            var matchedDocument = (from c in db.GetTable<Document>()
                                   where c.DocIDKey == SelectedRow.DocIDKey
                                   select c).SingleOrDefault();

            db.Documents.DeleteOnSubmit(matchedDocument);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            LoadCaseNumberKey(matchedDocument.CaseNumberKey, false, "documents");
            this.dataRepeater1.EndResetItemTemplate();
        }


    }
```

Any help would be great!.

Comment: why this line `if (this.dataRepeater1.CurrentItemIndex == 0)`?

Comment: @Mika  That line is not necessary you are correct.  That was there because I copied it from another button in which there has to be a currentitem to function.  Also I do not want this to fire if there is no record as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your are mixed up between your `documentsBindingSource` and your `dataRepeater`.
What you "see" visually is the dataRepeater, while what you "get", is the `documentsBindingSource.Current` (that you retrieve as being `SelectedRowView`) 
which is always set to 0 index. This is an all-too-common Winforms control trap.

Comment: thanks!  I actually fixed the issue just now by using the delete button on the binding navigator.